# Is taking the partial derivative of $x^n$ the same thing as the derivative of it?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is taking the partial derivative of $x^n$, the same thing as taking the derivative of $x^n$?  The derivative of $x^n$, is $nx^{n-1}$, so would the partial derivative be the same thing?

Comment: The partial derivative with respect to what variable? what is $x^n$ mapping from/to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, yes. We reserve the term "partial derivative" for functions of several variables. Sometimes I just say "take the derivative with respect to $x_j$ if my function is $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n)$" or something similar.

In single variable calculus, we just say "take a derivative" because you only have one variable. In your multivariable calculus course you'll see that we say "take a partial derivative" often. When we say "differentiate" as a generality, we may be referring to another type of derivative (divergence, gradient, curl, something like that).